# Integration $\int_{m}^\infty {x}{\sqrt{x^2 - m^2}}e^{-\beta x} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can the following integration be performed? Does it involve Bessel functions?$$\int_{m}^\infty {x}{\sqrt{x^2 - m^2}}e^{-\beta x} dx$$

**EDIT**: Actually, the original question is:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{y^2}{e^{-\beta \sqrt{y^2 + m^2}}} dy$$

Which means the lower limit is $m$ and not $0$ when $y$ is changed to $x$ as above. Accordingly the question has been edited. Thanks to @Jack D'Aurizio

Please give the final answer in some finite number. Elaboration of steps is encouraged.

Comment: didn't get the solution. what is $K_1$ and what are the other symbols?

Comment: Sorry, the first comment has some wrong symbols, fixed now. $K_1$ is the [modified Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1) $K_a(x)=\frac{\pi}2\frac{I_{-a}(x)-I_a(x)}{\sin(a\pi)}$

Comment: Relevant : $$\int_{m}^\infty \dfrac{x e^{-\beta x}}{\sqrt{x^2 - m^2}} dx=m K_1(m\beta),m>0,\Re(\beta)>0$$

Comment: The integrand function is not defined for $x\in[0,m)$, please fix your question.

Comment: Thank u. question edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it involves the **modified Bessel function of the second kind**.

$$\int_{m}^\infty {x}{\sqrt{x^2 - m^2}}e^{-\beta x} dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} m^2 \left(m K_1(\beta m)+\frac{1}{2} m (K_1(\beta m)+K_3(\beta m))\right)-m^3 K_1(\beta m)$$
$$=\frac{m^2}{β}K_2(mβ)$$

For getting the last equality, use the recurrence relation $$K_v(z)=K_{v-2}(z)+2\frac{v-1}{z}K_{v-1}(z)$$

http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/introductions/Bessels/05/

Comment: Are you sure? it should be $\frac{m^2}{\beta}K_2(m\beta)$.

Comment: @alexjo Yeah, it's just a different way of writing your result that looks simpler.

Comment: plz elaborate the steps. and what is the final value? can K_2 be solved to a finite value?
or do we have to leave it there?

Comment: @MycrofD Before posting this answer, I discussed with  Hippalectryon in a chat the formula he posted it above. I used it and differentiated it properly with respect to $\beta$ such that I got the integral you wanted to evaluate. I don't think you can simplify further the last expression.

Comment: ok. so the last exp cannot be simplified. but the steps.. i am sorry but i cannot get a hold of it. i am trying to use the definition (7) here at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html
K_1, K_2 and K_3 have different powers to [(x/m)^2 - 1]. So I dont see how they can be algebraically added or subtracted.

Comment: @MycrofD I used Mathematica to differentiate with respect to $\beta$. The answer is checked numerically and it's correct. When I'll have some time I'll expand the answer.

Comment: plz see the above comment by me. how could they be added knowing that K is defined by the definition given at (7)? somehow can you show me the steps? i d o not doubt your answer. but i don't understand it.

Comment: @MycrofD Use the recurrence relation $$K_v(z)=K_{v-2}(z)+2\frac{v-1}{z}K_{v-1}(z)$$

Answer (score 4):

With the substitution $x=mt$, the integral is:
$$J=m^3\int_1^{\infty} t\sqrt{t^2-1}\,e^{-m\beta t}\,dt$$
Consider,
$$I(a)=\int_1^{\infty} \sqrt{t^2-1}\,e^{-at}\,dt=\frac{K_1(a)}{a}$$
where I used identity 7 from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

To get the original integral, differentiate $I(a)$ with respect to $a$ and substitute $a=m\beta$, hence
$$I'(a)=-\frac{K_2(a)}{a} \Rightarrow J=\frac{m^2K_2(m\beta)}{\beta}$$
For the derivative, I had to use Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: what is the final answer? does it have to be in terms of K?
can't it be some finite value?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious substitution is $x=m\cosh t$, followed by recognizing the integral expression for the modified [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) $K_\alpha(u)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\exp(-u\cosh t)\cosh(\alpha t)~dt.$